# How to set representation for specific format on Json Serializer used by MicroProfile Rest Client?

Tags: java, json, rest, microprofile

How to set representation for specific format on Json Serializer used by MicroProfile Rest Client?

I have a service that requires a year-month input, formated as ISO 8601 "YYYY-MM". The server-side is working, and the response is correctly formatted, but implementation is Resteasy.

I'm using MicroProfile Rest Client, and entity attribute is defined as `java.util.YearMonth`.

The request is sent with serialized JSON year-month attribute represented as an object when I want it to be a formatted string.

Already tried annotating attribute with `JsonFormat`, `JsonbDateFormat` and `@Schema`, with same results.

Also tried adding Jackson Provider (ContextResolver), which works for the server-side, but no changes on the client-side.

Code snippet of testes annotations:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Schema;
import javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbDateFormat;

@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM")
@JsonbDateFormat(value = "yyyy-MM")
// Next one I'm guessing. Can't find docs for this.
@Schema(type = SchemaType.STRING, implementation = YearMonth.class, pattern = "yyyy-MM")
private YearMonth referencia;
```

Environment:

- Wildfly 21
- Java SE 11
- microprofile-rest-client-api:2.0
- microprofile-openapi-api:2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** First, you need to enable Jackson, as RESTEasy defaults to JSONB. For this you need to add this **system property**:

- **resteasy.preferJacksonOverJsonB = true**

Add system property as your preference, using `-Dproperty=value` command line syntax or whatever. In our case, we use WildFly configuration (e.g. standalone.xml):

```xml
<system-properties>
    <property name="resteasy.preferJacksonOverJsonB" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

**2.** Then you can add **Jackson configuration provider** to your REST client interface:

```java
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.annotation.RegisterProvider;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

@RegisterProvider(JacksonConfiguration.class)
@RegisterRestClient
public interface RestTestService {
    // methods...
}
```

Now, Java 8 Date Time API will correctly be serialized, and you can add custom formats with `@JsonFormat`, if needed.

---

Plus: Here a sample of a Jackson configuration provider that can be used on client and server-side too:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

@Provider
public class JacksonConfiguration implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public JacksonConfiguration() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```